# Differentiation of a complex function $f : U \subset C \mapsto C$

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider an open subset $U$ of the complex plane $U\subset C$, and $f:U \mapsto C$ a holomorphic function. So $f(z)=f(x+iy)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$. I would like to know if the rule of the derivatives for a real function $g:A\subset R \mapsto R$, for example the product rule, the chain rule, the quotient rule, etc, apply for the complex function $f$ ? For example, if I have a
$$f(z)=z^3+\frac{1}{z}$$
Can I say that
$$\frac{df}{dz}(z)=3z^2-\frac{1}{z^2}$$ ?

Comment: Yes, all those rules are applicable.

Comment: As @KaviRamaMurthy said. And I want to add that their proofs are verbatim the same as in the real case.